# How to learn about graph algorithms and some real world applications?

Tags: algorithms

I've read [Franco Moretti's work](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1844670260), but I'm looking for something more technical and perhaps broad in scope, if possible.  Specifically, I want to learn about techniques programmers are using to glean information from complex networks, eg clustering.  I'd also like to know what are some interesting questions/problems when it comes to graphs.

So far I've just skimmed academic papers with very specific applications.  I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I will go with the "broad side".

Let's go. I will list a couple of books that I'm using.

- [Graphs, Algorithms, and Optimization (Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584883960)
- [Modern Graph Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387984887)

Don't know if you dig python. But I'll list here some interesting stuff:

- http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/
- [Python Algorithms: Mastering Basic Algorithms in the Python Language](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430232374): you could just glimpse at the graph parts. This book is a "easy-reading" book.

Real world applications:

- Mining social data using [Facebook Open Graph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)
- [Mining the social web](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449388345): Introductory book that will show you the tools and how to start mining the social web.

I hope it helps =) cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[Travelling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) would be one of the more classic graph problems out there.  [List of NP-complete problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems) has a section on Graph Theory as well as Network Design.

[Flow network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network) would be an area of Mathematics around special kinds of graphs that may be of some help though it would help if you could narrow down the question a bit.